# How to @Autowired (inject) from xml. Could not autowire. No beans of 'DAO' type found

Tags: java, spring, code-injection

My beans.xml

```
<bean id = "DAO" class = "com.price.compare.service.DAO" scope="singleton" init-method="init">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type = "java.lang.String" value="localhost"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type = "java.lang.String" value="5432"/>
    ..
</bean>
```

Java controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/addproduct")
public class NewProductController {
   @Autowired
   private DAO database;  
   ...
```

DAO class

```
public class DAO {
private final String host;
private final String port;
private final String user;
private final String password;

private Connection connection;

public DAO(String host, String port, String user, String password) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
}


public void init() {
    connection = connect();
    if(testSelection()) {
        System.out.println("Connection to db successfully established");
    }
}
```

@Autowired
private DAO database;  <--- gives message "Could not autowire. No beans of 'DAO' type found. "

Comment: please provide the code that load the xml configuration file

Comment: How to load xml ?

Comment: of course, there should be a code inside your web.xml that tell spring where to load the beans.xml config file

Comment: check this link and web.xml file : https://hellokoding.com/spring-mvc-4-hello-world-example-with-xml-configuration-maven-and-jsp/

Comment: Code looks ok. please provide the full xml that contains the </beans>.

Answer (score 1):

You should add
`<context:component-scan base-package="packageName"/>`
into beans.xml
where packageName is package of DAO